# Understanding Chebyshev's Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm reading about Chebyshev's Theorem and I am seeing conflicting information.  My book states:

> Chebyshev's Theorem is a general result that applies to most discrete random variables (and most continuous probability distributions as well).

I was watching videos and other people talking about this theorem and they say this theorem applies to *any data set or distribution*.  Is this conflicting with my book when it says it applies to *most* random variables or are these two different statements?

The theorem is stated below:

> **Chebyshev's Theorem:**
>
> Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with finite mean $\mu_x$ and standard deviation $\sigma_x$.  Let $k$ be greater than $1$.  Then the probability that $X$ is more than $k$ standard deviations from the mean, $\mu_X$, is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{k^2}$.  That is:
>
> $\Pr\left(X < \mu_X -k \cdot \sigma_X \text{ or } X > \mu_X + k \cdot \sigma_X\right) = \Pr( \mid X - \mu \mid > k \cdot \sigma_X) \le  \cfrac{1}{k^2} \tag{1}$
>
> Equivalently,
>
> $\Pr\left( \mu_X -k \cdot \sigma_X \le X \le \mu_X + k \cdot \sigma_X\right) = \Pr( \mid X - \mu \mid \le k \cdot \sigma_X) \ge  1-\cfrac{1}{k^2} \tag{2}$

My second question is the difference between equations (1) and (2).  Is it correct to say that equation (1) is just setting an upper bound and equation (2) is setting a lower bound?  So basically equation (2) is just applying the First Axiom of Probability?  If so, why do the inequalitie in equation (2) become $ (\le X \le)$ from  simply ">"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The inequality states that the probability that $X$ takes values in a certain neighborhood of its mean is big enough (2), equivalently: the probability that it takes values that are far from the mean is small enough (2). It works for *any* probability distribution with finite variance $\sigma^2_X$ - that is, when the spread of data from the mean is not extremely big. Actually, in a present form it works for *any* distribution, since for those of infinite variance the inequalities are trivial.

Comment: Your (1) of $\Pr( \mid X - \mu \mid \gt k \cdot \sigma_X) \le  \cfrac{1}{k^2}$ is not the same as [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Probabilistic_statement) $\Pr( \mid X - \mu \mid \ge k \cdot \sigma_X) \le  \cfrac{1}{k^2}$ so I wonder what is the source for yours.

Comment: @Henry It is from the book Probability and Statistics with Applications:  A problem solving text by Asimow and Maxell.  I copied it directly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chebyshev's inequality applies to any discrete or continuous distribution which meets the conditions.  It is not particularly meaningful for some which do not, for example those which do not have a mean.

On your second question, what you really have in (1) is a statement of the form $\Pr(X \in A) \le c$; this clearly implies $\Pr(X \not\in A) \ge 1 - c$, which is the corresponding form of (2).  So you need to use the opposite of "$\gt$", which is "$\le$": if you had had "$\ge$" inside the $\Pr(\cdots)$ in (1), the (2) would have needed "$\lt$" inside.